# Can I remove an OTF macro from a Razer Deathstalker?

Tags: macros, razer-keyboard

I recently bought a Razer Deathstalker, and the other day I managed to activate the OTF macro recorder by accident, so now I have random gibberish and key presses bound to regular keys, so typing anything ends up being a pain, considering the backspace key prints "allallallallall", and so on.

The only way I've found of fixing this is reconnecting the keyboard or disabling Synapse, but that's only temporary, as it comes right back the next time I turn my PC on. Razer support mentions nothing related to removing them, and neither anywhere else I could imagine. There's also nothing in Synapse (god I hate Synapse).

How can I remove the macros?

Comment: There should be something in synapse or other software that was installed with it, for editing the macros.

Comment: @Raystafarian There is, but it seems to only be for macros that I've set up in Synpase. I have no other macros on my keyboard, so nothing shows up.

Answer (score 3):

I just figured it out myself.

Go to macro tab, within the macro tab there is a macro dropdown box. Click the arrow and choose one of them, then just delete any that you have.

It shows that none are there but you just have to go in and select one.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with all the gibberish.

Go to the first tab 'keyboard' then delete what ever profile you have and make a new one, that will remove any of the OTF macros you have.

Answer (score -1):

My solution was to simply create a new macro and bind it to the gibberish key. Example:
I bound U key to asdlldsl
I record a new otf macro (fn+f9)
I hit u key, macros aren't recorded when recording macros, then bind it to you by hitting fn+f9 then u

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

in the macro drop down box

Find a macro with a name like "new macro 1" or "new macro 2" and so on if you did not make the macros but there up in the box then just delete it.

you with see in the pic of the software all the keys being use by a macro are different looking in color

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.